# Asymptotic behaviour of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to understand how a solution of the ODE below behaves at infinity.
$$w(x)’’ = A w(x)^{-\alpha} + B w(x)^{-\beta} + C $$, with $A,B,C$ real constants and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ real, positive constants. Conventionally we take $\alpha$ is bigger than $\beta$.
I know that 
$$lim_{x \to \infty} w(x) = \tilde{w}$$ where $\tilde{w} $ is the root of the algebraic equation
$$ A w(x)^{-\alpha} + B w(x)^{-\beta} + C = 0 $$
My attempt went as follows.
I ”guessassume” $w$ has algebraic decay and write $$ w \sim Ex^{-\gamma}+ \frac{1}{2} \tilde{w} x^{2}$$ with $E$ and $\gamma$ other real positive constants. 
I perform the double derivation and obtain
$$w’’ =  E \gamma^{2} x ^{\gamma – 2} + C= A (  Ex^{-\gamma}+ \frac{1}{2} \tilde{w} x^{2}   )^{\alpha} + B   ( Ex^{-\gamma}+ \frac{1}{2} \tilde{w} x^{2} )^{\beta}+ C $$
Now some clever thinking about those parentheses would be required, and I am stuck...
Thanks for any help